# Synthesis of 2-Phenylcyclopentanone from cyclopentanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

My best try was to use aldol condensation after the reduction of the substrate(cyclopentanol) but that gives me a product with a methylphenyl substituent(2-Phenylcyclopentanone), nor a phenyl only.

Comment: This can be done in quite a few ways. It would be helpful if you told us what level of organic chemistry you were in to provide context for what types of reactions you have likely learned about.

Comment: @zhe now I'm studying reactions in alcohols, I already know about Sn1,Sn2,E1 and E2 reactions as like any reactions involving reductions and oxidation of functional groups. Actually, I'm learning nucleofilic substitutions. If you give one or more ways of proceeding that I don't fully understand, I will study that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1 dehydrate cyclopentanol to cyclopentene with conc Sulfuric acid

Step 2 epoxidise cyclopentene with m- Chloroperbenzoic acid

Step 3 open the epoxide with phenyl grignard to give 2-phenyl cyclopentanol

Step 4 oxidise to required product

Answer (score 3):

1) oxidise using your favourite method (pyridinium dichromate; metal catalyst and oxygen; hypochlorous acid etc.) to cyclopentanone. 
2) Pd catalysis using a bidentate ligand e.g. DPPF, with a hindered base, coupling the cyclopentanone to PhBr, to give the alpha-arylated product.
See JACS 1997, 119, p.12382 by John Hartwig.  This method works with isopropyl ketones also